# jQuery – How to move object to the left and right

Tags: jquery

I am pretty sure it's a very very easy question, but even after several hours of reading through Stackoverflow/Google.. still no luck.

How to create the effect of moving object like this carousel at the end of the website.

[Digital Media](http://wp1.themexlab.com/html/digital-media/index.html)

Effect of hand by clicking left(Of the Mouse) and move the object on both sides.

```css
/** page structure **/
#w {
  display: block;
  width: 750px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 45px;
}

#content {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 25px 20px;
  padding-bottom: 35px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0px 1px 2px 0px;
  -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0px 1px 2px 0px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0px 1px 2px 0px;
}

/** client logos **/
#clients {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

#clients .clients-wrap {
  display: block;
  width: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#clients .clients-wrap ul {
  display: block;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
}

#clients .clients-wrap ul li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 140px;
  height: 55px;
  line-height: 55px;
  text-align: center;
}
#clients .clients-wrap ul li img {
  vertical-align: middle;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s linear;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
  -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=65)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=65); 
  opacity: 0.65;
}
#clients .clients-wrap ul li img:hover {
  -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=100); 
  opacity: 1.0;
}
```

```html
<div id="w">
  <div id="content">
    <div id="clients">
      <h3>Past &amp; Present Clients</h3>
      <div class="clients-wrap">
        <ul id="clients-list" class="clearfix">
          <li><img src="http://wp1.themexlab.com/html/digital-media/img/resources/c-1.png" alt="Cartoon Network"></li>
          <li><img src="http://wp1.themexlab.com/html/digital-media/img/resources/c-2.png" alt="Rough Draft Studios"></li>
          <li><img src="http://wp1.themexlab.com/html/digital-media/img/resources/c-3.png" alt="SpongeBob Movie #2"></li>
          <li><img src="http://wp1.themexlab.com/html/digital-media/img/resources/c-4.png" alt="Apple Computers"></li>
          <li><img src="http://wp1.themexlab.com/html/digital-media/img/resources/c-5.png" alt="Google chat talk"></li>
          <li><img src="http://wp1.themexlab.com/html/digital-media/img/resources/c-6.png" alt="G4TV channel"></li>
          <li><img src="http://wp1.themexlab.com/html/digital-media/img/resources/c-3.png" alt="Wonka Chocolates and Candy"></li>
        </ul>
      </div><!-- @end .clients-wrap -->
    </div><!-- @end #clients -->
  </div><!-- @end #content -->
</div><!-- @end #w -->
```

Comment: I would recommend if you are open to using bootstrap - carousel - you need not do so much of code.. - it will b done in minutes.. just follow the example.. .http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel

Comment: Hello @HussainPatel ;) It is possible using the same effect using only jquery.

Comment: try this.. http://jsfiddle.net/mmarcon/UWbrQ/ Hope this helps..

Comment: @HussainPatel I do not exactly want the carousel. Only the Effect of hand by clicking left(Of the Mouse) and move the object on both sides. As the response of Fiido93. but only using jQuery. Please yes :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jquery `.animate()` to move object. Please take look [here](https://jsfiddle.net/vincentluth/kqxLf2jd/1/)

Or you can set the offset of element to move it left or right when you drag the mouse.

```
$element.offset({left: e.pageX - w/2});
```

A simple answer can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vincentluth/odpa9wed/1/), hope it can tackle more complex one if you have any.

Comment: @vicentluth Without buttons friend. Only the Effect of hand by clicking left(Of the Mouse) and move the object on both sides. As this moving object like this example at the end of the website. [Digital Media](http://wp1.themexlab.com/html/digital-media/index.html)

Comment: exactly what I needed but no buttons.

Comment: Move the object only with the mouse(holding the left mouse button).

Answer (score 0):

just use this jquery plugin thanks to [owl carousel 2](http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="owl-example" class="owl-carousel">

<div>
<img src="http://wp1.themexlab.com/html/digital-media/img/resources/c-1.png">
</div>

<div>
<img src="http://wp1.themexlab.com/html/digital-media/img/resources/c-1.png">
</div>

<div>
<img src="http://wp1.themexlab.com/html/digital-media/img/resources/c-1.png">
</div>

<div>
<img src="http://wp1.themexlab.com/html/digital-media/img/resources/c-1.png">
</div>

<div>
<img src="http://wp1.themexlab.com/html/digital-media/img/resources/c-1.png">
</div>

<div>
<img src="http://wp1.themexlab.com/html/digital-media/img/resources/c-1.png">
</div>

</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(function(){
owl();
})


function owl(){

$('#owl-example').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1
        },
        600:{
            items:3
        },
        1000:{
            items:5
        }
    }
})

}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/fido3993/b75wrxaz/1/)

Comment: Hello @Fiido93 ;) It is possible using the same effect using only jquery.

Comment: yep it is, but it take lot of code, don't repeat yourself. just use the plugin. :)

Comment: Digital media using that plugin too.

Comment: Too bad :(, it was a duty for college.

Comment: so this isn't answer that you looking for?